# Android - How do I launch a separate screen with information based on the selected ListView choice?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-activity

I have a list view which is displaying a list of all installed applications on the device. I am having trouble finding a way to launch a separate screen with information on based on the selected item in the list view.

For example: Clicking on 'Facebook' in the list view will open a screen with information I have typed about Facebook.

**Code**

```
public class ListApplications extends Activity {

private ListView lView;
 private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.list_applications);

  lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
  PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

  List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

  for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
   results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
   Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
  } 

 lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results)); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an onItemClicked listener to your list view and in the onItemClicked callback, you will know which item is clicked from the pos parameter. And from the results array you have defined in your code, you will know what to do next.

You can refer to the official tutorial at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Answer (score 1):

**I am using by position you can also use text of selected list item**

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
 int position, long id) {

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Detailedcontent.class);
intent.putExtra("selectedItemPosition", position);
startActivity(intent );

} 
});
}
```

**on Detailedcontent.class**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int position=bundle.getInt("selectedItemPosition");

switch(position)
{

case 1://if incase facebook position is one
//set content about fb

break;

}
```